# Conditional expectation inequality (short)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality

I am stumped with starting this problem. Could I please get some hints/ advice on tackling it:

Show

$$
\mathbb{E}[X\mid X \leqslant x] \leqslant \mathbb{E}[X]
$$

Thanks in advance!

EDIT (Solution):

Following Marcus's hint:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{P}[X≤x]\mathbb{E}[X|X≤x]+\mathbb{P}[X>x]\mathbb{E}[X|X>x]$$

and noting

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X≤x] \leqslant x < \mathbb{E}[X|X>x]$$

it follows that

$$\mathbb{E}[X] \geqslant \mathbb{P}[X≤x]\mathbb{E}[X|X≤x]+\mathbb{P}[X>x]\mathbb{E}[X|X≤x] = \mathbb{E}[X|X≤x].    $$

Note: It has been brought to my attention that there is an existing question on here almost identical to mine. It does not however have such a complete answer and so I leave it to the operators to remove this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Write $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x] \mathbb{E}[X \, | \, X \leq x] + \mathbb{P}[X > x] \mathbb{E}[X \, | \, X > x].$$

Comment: Thanks for the response!